# Al ejecutar evento de botón se desaparece el div que se controla su visibilidad con el valor de un RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, aspx

Estoy ocultando con JavaScript un div según el valor que tenga en `RadioButtonList`, esta parte funciona bien, pero en el div tengo un control para subir archivos y al momento que se da click en el botón guardar se ejecuta el evento, pero se desaparece todo el contenido del div. ¿Cómo puedo controlar para que no pase esto?

El código es:

- Función Javascript:

```js
  $(document).ready(function Ocultar () {
            $('#<%=rblBorQue.ClientID %>').click(function Ocultar () {
                    var SelectedValue = $('#<%=rblBorQue.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();

                if (SelectedValue == 1) {
                                $('#DivSeleccion').css("display", "none"); 
                            }
                else {
                     $('#DivSeleccion').css("display", "block");  
                  }
            });
            });
```

Y el código del aspx es:

```
  <div id="DivSeleccion" style="display:none;">  

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlTextoBorQue" runat="server" BorderColor="Orange" BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Justify" widht="600px">
               <asp:Panel ID="pnlTextoBorQue1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Justify" widht="600px">
           
                <table class="tablaContenido" cellpaddingleft="20px">
                       
                 <tr>
                   <td><asp:Label ID="lbTextoIndicaciones"  runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                   
                 </tr>

                                          
             </table>

                   </asp:Panel>
             </asp:Panel>
           
             <br/>
             
           
                 <table class="tablaContenido" cellpaddingleft="20px">

                     <tr>
                       <td></td>
                       <td></td>
                     </tr>
                     
                    <tr>
                       <td><asp:Label ID="lbSubirArchivosBorQue" runat="server" Text="- Seleccione el archivo:" Width="250px"></asp:Label></td>
                       <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fupSubirArchivosBorQue" BackColor="Yellow" class="multi" ToolTip="Seleccionar un archivo" Width="350px" runat="server" BorderColor="Orange"/> </td>

                    </tr>

                 
                     <tr>
                         <td><asp:Label ID="lbMsjSubirArchivo" runat="server" Text="- Subir el archivo seleccionado:" Width="250px"></asp:Label></td>
                         <td><asp:Button ID="btnCargarArchivo"  runat="server" Text="Subir Archivo" OnClick="btnCargarArchivo_Click" BorderColor="Orange" Height="20px" Width="350px" autopostback="true"/></td>
                         <td><asp:Label ID="lbMsjSubidaArchivos" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:Label></td>
                     </tr>
                         
                 </table>
            

              <br/>
       
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es que sea invisible, en vez de hacer un display: none; Prueba a ver de hacer un visibility: hidden;

```
$(document).ready(function Ocultar () {
$('#<%=rblBorQue.ClientID %>').click(function Ocultar () {
var SelectedValue = $('#<%=rblBorQue.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();

             if (SelectedValue == 1) {
                            $('#DivSeleccion').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
                        }
            else {
                 $('#DivSeleccion').css("visibility", "visible");  
              }
        });
        });
```

A lo mejor esto te sirve...